# Jeditable setting default selected value after change

Tags: jquery, jeditable

My app allows the user to update a field via a drop down box using jeditable. When the program is loaded i created this function to get the selected value and set it as the selected value in jeditable.

But after i change the value, the selected tag stays set as the old value. how can i make it change to the new value?

this is the function

```
function updateType(ID,type){
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#tweekType-'+ID).editable("edit.php?type=tweekType", {  

    data   : " {'copywriting':'Copywriting','design':'Design','code':'Code', 'selected':'"+type+"'}",
    type   : 'select'

    });
});
```

this is the wrapper around the tag.

```
<span id="tweekType-<?php echo $getTweaksReturned->tweekID; ?>">
<?php type($getTweaksReturned->type); ?>
<script>updateType('<?php echo $getTweaksReturned->tweekID; ?>','<? echo $getTweaksReturned->type; ?>'); </script>
</span>
```

The same tag is replicated on the page the returns the new variable.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same issue. The answers given here are not to the point.

Anyway, I solved it with a pretty simple and neat solution:

Just don't add the 'selected' key and value.

Every time you open the select box it's automatically on the value of the cell...

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have been searching for this answer for hours, this worked perfectly thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to trim the value. This is because of mysterious white spaces.

```
$('.edit').editable('/xxx/TableRowUpdate', {
...
data: function (value, settings) {
return " {'a':'category a','b':'category b','selected': '" + $.trim(value) + "'}";
},
...
```

Hope this can help!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks pretty un-jQuery like but it probably works. Is there a reason you are binding Jeditable to each id separately? Also is there a reason you are calling document.ready inside a function? Just give the span a class and bind to a class.

```
<span class="tweek" id="tweekType-<?php echo $getTweaksReturned->tweekID; ?>">
<?php type($getTweaksReturned->type); ?>
</span>
```

and the bind Jeditable to it inside inside document.ready (not a function). If select has value matching the text you click then it will selected by default. Note the design != Design. Do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tweekType-'+ID).editable("edit.php?type=tweekType", {  
       data   : " {'Copywriting':'Copywriting','Design':'Design','Code':'Code'}",
       type   : 'select'
    });
});
```

Or you can alternatively load the content of select from external url which returns and JSON array. Then the text and value of select do not need to match:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tweekType-'+ID).editable("edit.php?type=tweekType", {  
       loadurl : "http://www.example.com/select.php",
       type    : 'select'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't submitted values to a php script but when you call another javascript function with jeditable you have to return the value to be updated from the function so:

```
$(".selector").editable(someFunction, {
    indicator: "Saving...",
    tooltip: "Click to edit...",
    data: " {'3':'3','4':'4','5':'5'}",
    type: 'select',
});
```

then:

```
function someFunction(value, settings) {
  // do some magic
  return(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to pre-select the current selected value.

If it is pure client side you can override the data function:

```
 $('.edit').editable('/xxx/TableRowUpdate', {
   ...
   data: function (value, settings) {
     return " {'a':'category a','b':'category b','selected': '" + value + "'}";
   },
   ...
```

If it is server side you can use

```
$('.edit').editable('/xxx/TableRowUpdate', { 
     ...    
     loadurl: '/xxx/FileCategoryList',
     loadtype: "POST",
     loaddata: function(value, settings) {
                  return {selectedValue: value};
               },
```

The server side code (c# MVC example) would look like

```
public JsonResult FileCategoryList(string selectedValue)
{
  var categories = new Dictionary<string, string>{{"a", "a category"}, {"b", "b category"}, {"selected", selectedValue}};
    return Json(categories, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}
```